# Expression blend and mock data

Tags: .net, silverlight, expression-blend

I have an Item template and I want to design it, but I can't see what the stuff looks like in blend because I am databinding it to objects that doesn't exist in blend.

Is there a way that I can make fake data come up to do this?

They are textblocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options provided by blend and you can also use other techniques as well.

Here is the [link](http://silverzine.com/tutorials/how-to-create-sample-data-in-blend-3/) that explains how to add dummy data in blend for design purposes.

1. Create a dummy data source using blend and bind it to your control(look for advanced properties,databinding)
2. You can import xml data through blend.

[Click here](http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007091401.html) for the other techniques and more information

[click here for new blog post on design time data](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/ddesigninstance-ddesigndata-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As a very quick and simple solution you can supply a fallback value as follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, FallbackValue=Some text to show when binding fails}" />
```

Note that this will also show up in your application if `MyProperty` cannot be found.

If you want to bind a `ListBox` (or something else) to more complex data you can use Blend to create it, but this is probably overkill for your TextBlocks. See [this tutorial](http://silverzine.com/tutorials/how-to-create-sample-data-in-blend-3/) for a walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Create your dummy objects as form resources.  Bind your controls at design time to the resources, and then you can see your dummy data displayed at design time.